# IDS/IPS functionality via Iptables rule

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, intrusion-detection

Does Iptables have IDS/IPS functionality?

Linux: Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iptables does packet inspection/filtering/mangling. IDS and IPS are too broad terms to use in this context. Some functionality of iptables does fall in the scopes of IDS and IPS, dropping the packets on specific ports for example, but most of the IDS or IPS functionality will be out of what iptables can do.